# Conditional navbarPage menus

Tags: r, shiny

I have a question about conditional generation of navbarMenu based on the variable in the server-side. I created a small demo app to illustrate it.

```
ui = shinyUI(
    navbarPage(title = "Demo app",
               navbarMenu("Small numbers",
                          tabPanel("First small page", uiOutput("firstSmallPage"))
               ),
               navbarMenu("Big numbers",
                          tabPanel("First big page", uiOutput("firstBigPage"))
               )
    )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    rand_num = sample(1:10)[1]
    # if rand_num is higher than 5 I dont want Big number navbarMenu to appear
    print(rand_num)

    output$firstSmallPage <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("smallPlot")
    })
    output$smallPlot <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})

    output$firstBigPage <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("bigPlot")
    })
    output$bigPlot <- renderPlot({plot(990:1000)})
})

app = shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

What I am trying to archive is to hide Big Numbers tab if `rand_num` is higher 5. I tried wrapping `navbarMenu`s in `renderUI` on the server-side and replacing it with `uiOutput` in the ui-side but it was unsuccessful. It is crucial for solution to work with more than 2 `navbarMenu`s. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
ui = shinyUI(
  navbarPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    title = "Demo app",
    navbarMenu("Small numbers",
               tabPanel("First small page", uiOutput("firstSmallPage"))
    ),
    navbarMenu("Big numbers", 
               tabPanel("First big page", uiOutput("firstBigPage"))
    )

  )
)

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  rand_num = sample(1:10)[1]
  # if rand_num is higher than 5 I dont want Big number navbarMenu to appear
  print(rand_num)
  if(rand_num>5){
    hide(selector = ".navbar-nav li:nth-child(3)")
  }

  output$firstSmallPage <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("smallPlot")
  })
  output$smallPlot <- renderPlot({plot(1:10)})

  output$firstBigPage <- renderUI({
    plotOutput("bigPlot")
  })
  output$bigPlot <- renderPlot({plot(990:1000)})
})

app = shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
runApp(app)
```

Comment: I am guessing that in `.navbar-nav li:nth-child(3)` we have 3 because the `navbarMenu` I want to hide is the last one? Does it mean that I will have to use order to indicate which `navbarMenu` I want to hide?

Comment: @user974514 Yes. I don't know another way to select it.